# spice plot resolution - sinusoid does not look continuous

Tags: spice

### Problem

How does one increase the resolution of a SPICE plot? My sinusoidal signal doesn't look continuous, it looks very 'pointy'.  I am using [MACSPICE3](http://www.macspice.com) to simulate a non-inverting op-amp by using a dependent source (VCVS).  Changing the step parameter of the *tran* command has not helped.

I understand that results data is stored in a construct called a plot, which is comprised of vectors.  Is this pointy phenomena linked to the data in these constructs, or the graphical representation?

### Example of a pointy plot

[image: Pointy SPICE plot]

### Netlist

> Basic Non-Inverting OpAmp
>
> V1 2 0 AC sin(0 10 50 0 0) DC 0
>
> RBogus 2 0 10K
>
> e 3 0 2 1 999K
>
> R1 3 1 10K
>
> R2 1 0 10K
>
> .control
>
> delete all
>
> tran 1.0ns 100ms
>
> plot v(1) v(2) v(3)
>
> op
>
> display
>
> print all
>
> show all
>
> .endc
>
> .end

Note:

RBogus exists to create a closed loop for the ac source.

Comment: If it's generic SPICE syntax, try `.tran 0 100m 0 10u`. `1u` is the timestep.

Comment: @A Concerned Citizen, Thanks for your input.
Macspice uses the syntax:
.TRAN TSTEP TSTOP [ [ TSTART ] TMAX ] [ UIC ]
So my analysis should step at increments of one nanosecond, for 100 milliseconds.  I have just learned that TMAX and the TSTEP work in conjunction with each other. I will post an answer

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, which version(s) of spice would you recommend? Macspice doesn't seem to have the support that LTSpice or PSpice have for instance. Would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Glad it worked out, but I wouldn't recommend one SPICE over another simply because that works for me. De gustibus... The best tool in the world is the one that suits you best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is

.TRAN TSTEP TSTOP [ [ TSTART ] TMAX ] [ UIC ]

Changing

> *tran 1.0ns 100ms*

To

> tran 1us 100ms 0 1us

has solved the issue. In the user guide, note that the TSTEP doesn't exclusively control the step size.  TMAX must also be set. The boldface text explains why.

> - TSTEP is the printing or plotting increment for line-printer output. For use with the post-processor, TSTEP is the suggested computing increment.
> - TSTOP is the final time
> - TSTART is the initial time. If TSTART is omitted, it is assumed to be zero. The transient analysis always begins at time zero. In the interval , the circuit is analyzed (to reach a steady state), but no outputs are stored. In the interval , the circuit is analyzed and outputs are stored.
> - TMAX is the maximum step-size that SPICE uses; **for default, the program chooses either TSTEP or (TSTOP-TSTART)/50.0, whichever is larger**. TMAX is useful when one wishes to guarantee a computing interval which is smaller than the printer increment, TSTEP.
>     [image]
>     http://www.macspice.com/ug/sec4.html#s4.3.9